# Hover a div behind another div

Tags: css, html, hover, containers

Imagine this kind of strucure :

```
<div class="background">
  <div class="object"></div>
</div>
<div class="foreground"></div>
```

My `foreground` totally overlays my `background` 
In my CSS I would like to change object property on hover (ie `.object:hover{}` )
Is there way to do that in CSS without moving my `object` inside `foreground` or using js ?

Update : My css as asked.

```
.background { background:url('background.svg') no-repeat; }
.foreground { background:url('foreground.svg') no-repeat 50% 50%; }
.object {
 position: absolute;
 top:10px;
 left:10px;
 opacity:1;
}

.object:hover 
{
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

Comment: You can use a z-index to tell which div you want to be on top

Comment: Can you add your css please.

Comment: You won't be able to hover over the object if the foreground element is covering it up. Can you post the css for your background and foreground elements as well?

Comment: The absolute best way for us to help you on this is to also let us know what exactly your end goal is. You want to change what properties to object exactly? What will it be doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is kind of. You can use sibling selector (`+`), but you must revert order of your divs.

Example CSS:

```
.background {
    position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: red;
}

.foreground {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 150px;
    top: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 1;
}

.object {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
}

.foreground:hover + .background .object {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div class="foreground"></div>
<div class="background">
    <div class="object"></div>
</div>
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/pBYwT/1/

Answer (score -2):

Higher z-index for div:hover which you want to display on top.

Comment: He'd like to change `.object` style on `.foreground:hover`.